# How to record audio, apply echo effect, and save to a file using Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk, audio-recording

I am developing an app which recording audio from MIC, applying echo effect, and saving to the file. The NDK sample from google [audio-echo](https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/audio-echo) does the similar things, but not saving the recorded audio to the file. How could we save that recorded audio to the file? Or could we have other options to achieve these?